# Merging two tables to one parent table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with 2 columns ID, Name, Now I am trying to make a two different data with the same table that will come around 2 new tables but I want both the table rows merged into parent table.

I will explain with sample data:

Parent table:

```
ID    Name
1      abc
2      def
```

I am writing a select query as

```
Select ID, Name||'_First' as a from table
```

This will give me

```
ID    Name
1      abc_First
2      def_First
```

Now my another select query as

I am writing a select query as

```
Select ID, Name||'_Second' as b from table
```

This will give me

```
ID    Name
1      abc_second
2      def_Second
```

Now I am trying to join both the queries and produce the parent table as

Tried like this:

```
Select ID,a,b from
(Select ID, Name||'_First' as a from table
Inner join
Select ID, Name||'_Second' as b from table)
on joins here
```

But this is producing me 3 columnslike

```
ID    a              b
1      abc_First   abc_second
2      def_First   def_Second
```

But I need as

```
ID    Name
    1      abc_First
    2      def_First
    1      abc_second
    2      def_Second
```

I am stuck at this point.

Comment: I think your end result is confusing. Can you edit your question for better visualization.

Comment: @ILLUMINATI7590 thanks for your reply...please my edited post

Comment: Ok, I think you got your answer

Comment: Yes...can you please help bit more..Thanks but if i nned to select using sub query how can i do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use union all

```
Select ID, Name||'_First' as name from table
    union all
    Select ID, Name||'_Second' as name from table
```

Comment: Thanks but if i nned to select using sub query how can i do that.

Comment: Sub query means by comparing both table id's??

Comment: Yes...exactly...please help